# Update Notification in Capacitor's Local Notification Plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

Is there any alternative [capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/) community plugin with a function to update the emitted notification.

There was a [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) plugin [cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) which has the ability to update the emitted notification

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.update({
    id: 15,
    text: [{ person: 'Irish', message: 'Bye bye' }]
});
```

[Capacitor's](https://capacitorjs.com/) Local notification plugin
[@capacitor/local-notifications](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/local-notifications) doesn't have this support.

Wondering is any plugin available like this in capacitor.

Comment: Have you tried to combine `getDeliveredNotifications()` to retrieve notification content and `schedule()` to post updated notification in Capacitor's official plugin?

Comment: Yes, it triggers new notification not updating the existing.

Comment: not sure if what I'll send will fit your needs, but still will send ideas and perhaps you may have already tried but anyway.. After getting the delivered notifications, if you got the notification id you wanted, and triggered a new notification with the same id of the previous sent notification, will it be replaced? If not, maybe you could go with another approach, maybe it's not a perfect solution but still may give you what you want which is: after you get the notification id, cancel the notification then trigger it again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android](https://developer.android.com/) will update the notification when the same notification id is passed.

we can use **setOnlyAlertOnce** flag if we would only like the sound, vibrate and ticker to be played if the notification is not already showing.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification#Updating

While I'm going through the [Capacitor's](https://capacitorjs.com/) Local Notification Plugin's Native Android code noticed there was method **dismissVisibleNotification(id)** which is canceling the existing notification.

Hence the updated notification looks like a new notification.

```
@Nullable
    public JSONArray schedule(PluginCall call, List<LocalNotification> localNotifications) {
        JSONArray ids = new JSONArray();
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

        boolean notificationsEnabled = notificationManager.areNotificationsEnabled();
        if (!notificationsEnabled) {
            if (call != null) {
                call.reject("Notifications not enabled on this device");
            }
            return null;
        }
        for (LocalNotification localNotification : localNotifications) {
            Integer id = localNotification.getId();
            if (localNotification.getId() == null) {
                if (call != null) {
                    call.reject("LocalNotification missing identifier");
                }
                return null;
            }
            dismissVisibleNotification(id);
            cancelTimerForNotification(id);
            buildNotification(notificationManager, localNotification, call);
            ids.put(id);
        }
        return ids;
    }
```

```
private void dismissVisibleNotification(int notificationId) {
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this.context);
    notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
}
```